# ECSlidingViewController swipe gesture issue on View Controller

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uipangesturerecognizer, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using ECSlidingViewController for my app for the slide out menu and having a imageview on my all view controllers. It works perfectly but when i to the right when the menu controller(Slide view) is open the imageview with all the uiview items move to the right and shows a white background and dismiss the view controller.

Comment: So tapping the button works, but swiping doesn't work? I suspect there might be something else going on. How are you adding the image views?

Comment: Another thing to consider is upgrading ECSlidingViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've struggled too in the beginning when I used ECSlidingViewController.

This video tutorial helped me a lot

http://youtu.be/tJJMyzdB9uI
(Check part 2 and 3 also).